# Is this a induced sub graph of the the following graph G?

Tags: graphs

This is graph G:
[image]

I am required to find as much as 15 induced subgraphs, but so far I only found 3. Which are: a-b-d-e, b-c-e-f and a-b-c-e.

I was wondering if a-d-e-f would also be counted as an induced subgraph and other of this similar arrangement.

Comment: You might want to read the definition of an induced subgraph again.  For example, the graph with only one vertex ($K_1$)is an induced subgraph of your graph, and so is the graph with two connected vertices ($K_2$) and two disconnected vertices (2$K_1$), the triangle ($K_3$) etc.

Comment: There are more than 15 induced subgraphs. Depending on how you count, there could be 63 or even 64 induced subgraphs. Perhaps you're looking for *non-isomorphic* induced subgraphs?